# Google Analytics 4 Request URLs (Data protection)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

When the gtm.js script is included in a site, sometimes calls are made to [https://www.googletagmanager.com/a?id=[....]](https://www.googletagmanager.com/a?id=%5B....%5D) (For example in the tag which is included in the Google Store: https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-MX89MJ - currently in the line 154)

During the investigation of the script, it seems that about 5 out of 1.000 sessions are triggering these calls (Configured in the script via sampleRate:"0.005000")

I tried to figure out whats the reason for these calls - what is happening with the passed data? Unfortunately I couldn't find an explanation in the documentation, stackoverflow etc.

Does anyone know what these calls are for?

**Edit**:

*Sample Request* (Followed by some other calls with different e-Query-Parameters - instead of gtm.init_consent - like gtm.init or literally '*')

```
GET https://www.googletagmanager.com/a?id=GTM-MX89MJ&cv=760&v=3&t=t&pid=726029121&rv=6f0&es=1&e=gtm.init_consent&eid=-1&tc=385&z=0
```

*Response (Statuscode 204)*

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://store.google.com
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-length: 0
content-type: image/gif
cross-origin-resource-policy: cross-origin
date: Tue, 21 Jun 2022 15:24:10 GMT
expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
server: Google Tag Manager
vary: *
x-xss-protection: 0
```

Comment: Can you please share the network request example if you have it? I wonder what it passes with that request.

Comment: @BNazaruk Sure - just added a sample request, which is sent from store.google.com

Comment: It looks like the request doesn't contain current page url. That was my main concern (due to PII). But generally, it looks like this is how Google tracks GTM usage over the web. trying to confirm it. Doesn't look like it's super compliant with GDPR.

Comment: @BNazaruk did you get the chance to confirm your guess?

Comment: nah, I don't wanna bother, but I'm pretty sure that if I'm not exactly right, I'm super close. It's a matter of testing now, exactly as suggested in the tip there.